# File Browser Window on Android>=6 with PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap, file-browser

I'm having trouble opening a file browser window on Android6+. I'm using latest Cordova/PhoneGap with Visual Studio 2017. When I click the desired button, nothing happens. When I deploy my source code on a webserver and access this site on my tablet, everything works fine. A live example can be seen at:
http://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/. "Upload zip file" won't open a file browser.

```
<div class="ui teal fluid labeled icon button upload" id="zipfile" data-content="Mandatory files : SHP , DBF" data-variation="inverted large">
                    Upload zip file
                    <i class="file archive outline icon"></i>
                    <input type="file" id="file" accept=".zip">
            </div>
```

My code (from https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js)

```
 function loadShpZip() {
            var epsg = ($('#epsg').val() == '') ? 4326 : $('#epsg').val(),
                encoding = ($('#encoding').val() == '') ? 'UTF-8' : $('#encoding').val();
            if (file.name.split('.')[1] == 'zip') {
                if (file) $('.dimmer').addClass('active');
                loadshp({
                    url: file,
                    encoding: encoding,
                    EPSG: epsg
                }, function (data) {
                    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL,
                        url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: "application/json" }));

                    $('#link').attr('href', url);
                    $('#link').html(file.name + '.geojson' + '<i class="download icon"></i>').attr('download', file.name + '.geojson');

                    $('#downloadLink').slideDown(400);

                    $('.shp-modal').toggleClass('effect');
                    $('.overlay').toggleClass('effect');
                    $('#wrap').toggleClass('blur');

                    vector.addData(data);
                    map.fitBounds([
                        [data.bbox[1], data.bbox[0]], [data.bbox[3], data.bbox[2]]
                    ]);
                    $('.dimmer').removeClass('active');
                    $('#preview').addClass('disabled');
                    $('#epsg').val('');
                    $('#encoding').val('');
                    $('#info').addClass('picInfo');
                    $('#option').slideUp(500);

                    newData = data;

                    for (var i = 0; i < newData.features.length; i++) {
                        var c1 = newData.features[i].geometry.coordinates;

                        for (var u = 0; u < c1.length; u++) {
                            var c2 = c1[u];

                            for (var o = 0; o < c2.length; o++) {
                                var oldCoordinate = c2[o];
                                var newCoordinate = [oldCoordinate[1], oldCoordinate[0]];
                                c2[o] = newCoordinate;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    globaljson = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

                });
            } else {
                $('.modal').modal('show');
            }
        }
        initVector();

        $("#file").change(function (evt) {
            file = evt.target.files[0];
            if (file.size > 0) {
                $('#dataInfo').text(' ').append(file.name + ' , ' + file.size + ' kb');
                $('#option').slideDown(500);
                $('#preview').removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });

        $('#preview').click(function () {
            loadShpZip();
        });

        $('.button').popup({
            //inline: true,
            position: 'bottom left'
        });
        $('.tips').popup({
            target: '#addZipfile',
            position: 'top center'
            //variation: 'huge'
        });
        $('#entireLayer').click(function () {
            map.fitBounds(vector.getBounds());
            chrome.storage.local.set({ 'key': 'value' });
            chrome.storage.local.get('key', function (obj) {
                alert(obj.key);
            });

        });
        $('#addZipfile').click(function () {
            $('.shp-modal').toggleClass('effect');
            $('.overlay').toggleClass('effect');
            $('#wrap').toggleClass('blur');
        });
        $('#cancel').click(function () {
            $('.shp-modal').toggleClass('effect');
            $('.overlay').toggleClass('effect');
            $('#wrap').toggleClass('blur');
        });
        $('#removeLayer').click(function () {
            $('#attr').fadeOut(300);
            window.location.reload();
        });
        $('#encoding').dropdown();
        $('.v').change(function () {
            var msg = '<div class="msg" id="msg" style="display: none;"><div class="ui primary inverted red segment">' +
                '<p>You can find the EPSG Code of your Shapefile on <strong>spatialreference.org</strong></p></div><br /></div>';
            if ($('#epsg').val().match(/^\d{4}$/) != null) {
                $('#zipfile').removeClass('disabled');
                $('.msg').slideUp(750);
            } else {
                if ($('.msg')[0] == undefined) {
                    $('#epsgField').after(msg);
                    $('.msg').slideDown(1500);
                }
            }
        });

        $("#attr").draggable({ containment: $(this).parent().parent(), scroll: false, cursor: "move" });
        $('#cancelAttr').click(function () { $('#attr').hide() 
});
```

I've set my permissions in config.xml like this:

```
     <platform name="android">
       <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
         android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
         android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       </config-file>
     </platform>
```

When I check my app for requested permissions, none show up tho.

This Problem does not exist on a tablet with Android 4.4.

edit: a few logs, which I don't really understand.

```
07-04 12:10:20.471 18340 18340 W CordovaInterfaceImpl: Got an activity result, but no plugin was registered to receive it.
07-04 12:10:20.471 18340 18340 D WebView : resumeTimers
07-04 12:10:20.471 18340 18340 D WebView : setNetworkAvailable=true
07-04 12:10:20.472 18340 18340 D ActivityThread: SEND_RESULT handled : 0 / ResultData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@7c8f400 results[ResultInfo{who=null, request=5173, result=0, data=null}]}
07-04 12:10:20.482   202  2362 I BufferQueueProducer: [io.cordova.myappac1b3c/io.cordova.myappac1b3c.MainActivity](this:0x7f9222e400,id:306,api:1,p:18340,c:202) queueBuffer: fps=6.96 dur=1149.87 max=176.61 min=134.62
07-04 12:10:20.530   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Down:71182195, ID:0, Index:1969346496
07-04 12:10:20.530   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableAsync:3
07-04 12:10:20.611   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Up:71182277, ID:0, Index:1969349888
07-04 12:10:20.611   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableTimeoutMsAsync:3, 100
07-04 12:10:20.696   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Down:71182362, ID:0, Index:1969346496
07-04 12:10:20.696   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableAsync:3
07-04 12:10:20.766   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Up:71182431, ID:0, Index:1969349888
07-04 12:10:20.766   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableTimeoutMsAsync:3, 100
07-04 12:10:20.838   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Down:71182504, ID:0, Index:1969346496
07-04 12:10:20.838   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableAsync:3
07-04 12:10:20.886   783  1017 D PowerManagerService: userActivityFromNative
07-04 12:10:20.887   783  1017 D PowerManagerService: userActivityNoUpdateLocked: eventTime=71182552, event=2, flags=0x0, uid=1000
07-04 12:10:20.887   783  1017 D PowerManagerNotifier: onUserActivity: event=2, uid=1000
07-04 12:10:20.887   783  1017 D PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=72975552 (in 1792999 ms)
07-04 12:10:20.887   783  1017 D DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=102, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=1.0, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=true, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
07-04 12:10:20.887   783  1017 I PowerManagerService: setBrightness mButtonLight 0.
07-04 12:10:20.887   783  1017 D PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x23, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
07-04 12:10:20.908   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Up:71182574, ID:0, Index:1969349888
07-04 12:10:20.908   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableTimeoutMsAsync:3, 100
07-04 12:10:20.957   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Down:71182623, ID:0, Index:1969346496
07-04 12:10:20.957   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableAsync:3
07-04 12:10:21.039   783  1018 D InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Up:71182705, ID:0, Index:1969349888
07-04 12:10:21.039   783  1018 I PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableTimeoutMsAsync:3, 100
07-04 12:10:21.080   783  2792 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=.zip} from uid 10111 from pid 18340 on display 0
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=.zip }
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3968)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.startActivityForResult(CordovaActivity.java:332)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3920)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.startActivityForResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:67)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser(SystemWebChromeClient.java:268)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.showFileChooser(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:481)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.runFileChooser(AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:70)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:7)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-04 12:10:21.082 18340 18340 W No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
07-04 12:10:21.083 18340 18340 D WebView : setNetworkAvailable=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing the very same issue (on visual studio 2015 and 2017)... it turns out something may be wrong with the plugin at this time.

I came up with a simple yet clever solution that allows me to select files from the device gallery without the use of any cordova plugins.

The answer is to create a separate .html page with the usual

```
<input type="file" name="File2Upload" id="File2Upload">
**...and other form elements**
```

Then introduce that newly created external .html page (with the contents of your form) to your main app via iFrame. Clicking on the input button will instantly open up the device photo gallery or recent photos... but you are not limited to just the photo gallery.. you can then navigate to any directory you wish.

The downside to this method of course is the ugly looking **choose file** input button that refuses to accept css styling; if you want full control over the look and feel of your file chooser button you will need to write some extra html and css like;

> Add a new div below the file picker input tag... then place a new input tag in
>   that newly created div... make sure the div at the top is directly above the div below... then hide the ugly original div at the top, now.. once the input tag at the bottom is of type "button" you will be able to style it as you please.

Finally you will need to add an on-change-event to the original div at the top(opacity 0)... so that it updates the styled/visible file chooser input at the bottom. Remember, the real input chooser is at the top but it is not visible because we are unable to style it... so the visible input will need to be updated to show the selected file.

...of course, if you don't mind the look of the original file chooser button then you would have a lot less work to do.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing input type into

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Seems like something in the compile process or Android 6 processing doesn't quite like the `accept=.zip` parameter on input fields.